# Какую графическую библиотеку использовать C++?

Tags: c++, графика, поиск-библиотек

Подскажите простую и легковесную графическую библиотеку, для представления двухмерного массива в виде квадратного поля n*n, с возможностью добавления изображений, текстур в клетки.

Answer (score 5):

Если вас интересует именно "легковесные" (который к тому же обладают отличной переносимостью), то посоветую `SDL` или `SFML`. Последним не пользовался, но `SDL` в связке с `OpenGL ES` показывает себя превосходно (если не хотите возиться с шейдерами, то у `SDL` есть расширения, которые позволяют выводить текстуры без написания собственных шейдеров).

Answer (score 2):

Ну, как минимум классика - [Qt](https://www.qt.io/), [GTK](https://www.gtk.org/). Если хочется что то нестандартное, то можно за [Nuklear](https://github.com/vurtun/nuklear) потрогать, хотя он и на C.

Nuklear:
[image: Nuklear]

Comment: Не думаю что эти библиотеки можно назвать "легковесными"

Comment: Тут проблема в другом. Код желательно писать такой, чтобы его могли подхватить другие программисты, и не просто подхватить, а не тратить время на изучения чего-то нового. Поэтому лучше всего брать чтото мейнстримное. Конечно, если это пет-проект, то можно брать что угодно, just4fun...

Comment: нет, проблема как раз-таки в легковесности - если думаете по другому, то попробуйте перенести приложение с Qt на android или wx-works. Перенести какой-нибудь `SDL` в 10 000 раз проще просто из-за объема зависимостей не говоря уж о кодовай базе. Если речь о приложении на стационарный комп под линукс и/или виндоус, то я с вами согласен, но не когда речь о простеньком выводе текстуры и пожеланием автора "легковесности"

Comment: qt умеет андроид из коробки: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/android.html а на остальные не-мейнстримные ОС переносить будет сложно любубю библиотеку. Собственно, поэтому надо сначала определить платформы, на которых планируется запускать проект и только потом выбирать библиотеки. Ну и наконец, если платформа не указана то по умолчанию это всё-таки linux-mac-win, либо вообще только win.

Comment: вы почему-то сами додумываете из головы то, чего не было в вопросе, при этом игнорируя то, что в этом вопросе черным по белому написано! Я понимаю, что вы основываетесь на личном опыте, но вы не думали, что у других опыт может быть иной? И когда человек пишет "легковесный" он с большой долей вероятности может иметь ввиду именно маленькую библиотеку, а не гиганский фреймворк вроде Qt. PS по поводу того что там умеет Qt из коробки: по поводу переносимости Qt - просто смешно. Вы в курсе, что, например в Qt на linux и windows по разному функционирует цикл обработки событий при drag&drop?

Comment: 1. В вопросе про платформу ни слова. 2. Ну, nuclear я упомянул. 3. У меня есть проект на куте linux-win-mac. Никаких проблем, вообще. Только с winXP приходится Qt 5.6 поддерживать ибо следующие куте не умеют ХР. 4. Я думаю, не стоит тут спорить. Мир-дружба-пиво и вот это вот всё. Просто поставьте минус ответу если не согласны :)

Comment: минус означает, что ответ содержит грубую ошибку, а не не согласие с мнением, так что ставить минус тут не за что